# VBA Copy Cell Contents to a cell in next row down if not blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in columns A thru H. Some rows have data in H. If there is data in H I need to insert a row before the next row and copy the contents of H to the new row into cell F.

All the example code I've found wants to put the data at the end of the table in the next open row.

I've found code to insert a row if H is not blank.

I need something to copy H if not blank to the next row down and into the cell in column F.

What I've done so far:

```
Sub SetupData()
    'This copies specific cells from PasteDataHere worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim s1 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim s2 As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim iLastCellS2 As Excel.Range
    Dim iLastRowS1 As Long

    Set s1 = Sheets("PasteDataHere")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Step1")

    ' get last row of H in PasteDataHere
    iLastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into
    Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)

    'copy into Step1
    s1.Range("H1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "H")).Copy iLastCellS2

    ' get last row of I in PasteDataHere
    iLastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row

    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into
    Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)

    'copy into Step1
    s1.Range("I1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "I")).Copy iLastCellS2
    
    ' get last row of K in PasteDataHere
    iLastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row

    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into
    Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)

    'copy into Step1
    s1.Range("K1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "K")).Copy iLastCellS2
    
    ' get last row of M in PasteDataHere
    iLastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into
    Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)

    'copy into Step1
    s1.Range("M1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "M")).Copy iLastCellS2
    
    ' get last row of N in PasteDataHere
    iLastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row

    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into
    Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)

    'copy into Step1
    s1.Range("N1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "N")).Copy iLastCellS2
    
    ' get last row of E in PasteDataHere
    iLastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into
    Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)

    'copy into Step1
    s1.Range("E1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "E")).Copy iLastCellS2
    
    ' get last row of G in PasteDataHere
    iLastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row

    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into
    Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)

    'copy into Step1
    s1.Range("G1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "G")).Copy iLastCellS2
   
    ' get last row of H in PasteDataHere
    iLastRowS1 = s1.Cells(s1.Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row

    ' get last AVAILABLE cell to past into
    Set iLastCellS2 = s2.Cells(s2.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0)

    'copy into Step1
    s1.Range("S1", s1.Cells(iLastRowS1, "S")).Copy iLastCellS2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    'this step puts a space below any row that has data in "H"
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Range("H1:H62555")
        If Not IsEmpty(rng) Then
            rng.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What have you done this far? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm trying to take a spreadsheet, rearrange the columns then move anything in column H to an inserted blank row just below it into column F

Comment: Not sure where to add code done so far.

Comment: Where's the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer below is based entirely on your question, and not on the code you provided.  It is based on the data being in Sheet1 - change as required.

When inserting rows, you need to work from the bottom up - otherwise your defined range (which changes with every inserted row) throws your code out.

Try this & let me know how you go.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SetUpData()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim Lastws1 As Long, i As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<~~ change sheet name to suit

Lastws1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

Set Rng = Sheet1.Range("H2:H" & Lastws1)

For i = Lastws1 To 1 Step -1
    
    If Rng.Item(i) <> "" Then
            Rng.Item(i).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
            Rng.Item(i).Offset(1, -2) = Rng.Item(i).Value
    End If

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```